# How to get rid of "C:\Windows\TEMP :: Unwriteable" in VirtueMart?

Tags: windows, joomla3.0, shared-hosting, virtuemart, writable

I've installed VirtueMart on my host on server. Everything works nice, but uploading photo/file. There are two problems:

1. I don't know how and where to set the TEMP folder. The default 'temp' folder is: "C:\Windows\TEMP" which is "Unwriteable". I should set it to a folder inside project, like following folders.
2. I can't make "\wwwroot\images\stories\virtuemart\typeless\resized\" folder "Unwriteable".

I have installed VirtueMart on Joomla 3.4, on a SHARED windows server on Arvixe.com, so I don't have access to "C:\Windows". I should change this predefined address in a way, but don't know how!

```
C:\Windows\TEMP :: Unwriteable
E:\HostingSpaces\MYUSERNAME\MYSITENAME.com\wwwroot\images\stories\virtuemart\typeless\ :: Writeable
E:\HostingSpaces\MYUSERNAME\MYSITENAME.com\wwwroot\images\stories\virtuemart\typeless\resized\ :: Unwriteable
```

I'd highly appreciate if you give me a hand. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like permissions issue. Do you have admin privileges on the server? If so check what the permission settings are on `wwwroot\images\stories\virtuemart\typeless\` (the only writable one) and copy them all over to which ever folder it is you want to put your stuff in.

Comment: Note you can see the permissions on a folder by right clicking on it, going to the Security tab.

Press the edit button and then you can add / remove different users / groups from being able to read / write to this folder.

BUT - If you are on a shared hosting server you may not have permission to to do this on all folders - particularly the C:\Windows folder

Comment: @SimonMerrick Thanks for your comments. You pointed exactly to my problem. My website is on a shared server. I should find a way to change this predefined address, but don't know how. I searched the whole project and database for "c:\windows" expression, but didn't find anything.